# What does it mean in UML that instance could realize more than 1 classifier?

Tags: class, uml, instance

Does any programming language provide such a thing?

Where could this be used?

For example:

[image]

note that somethingStrange is not a class, its an instance (its underlined) and this is an object diagram

Spec (section 7.3.22) says:

An instance specification is depicted using the same notation as its classifier, but in place of the classifier name appears an underlined concatenation of the instance name (if any), a colon (‘:’) and the classifier name or names.

The convention for showing multiple classifiers is to separate their names by commas.

So im stuck with "multiple classifiers".

Comment: this is not UML notation

Comment: i cant attach a picture, does this looks better?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45912725/cat-o-panzer.png

Comment: I've attached the pic for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any language with extensional rather than intensional typing will allow such constructs.

For example, in RDF two sources could make claims about a web resource which are completely conflicting, or in a 'duck type' language an object could have all the characteristics of two otherwise unrelated types.

Extensional languages classify objects by their properties - if it has prongs it's a fork, if it's got a handle and a bowl it's a spoon, if it has both prongs and a bowl it is both a fork and a spoon.

The difference between such languages and class oriented intensional languages such as C++/Java/C#  to which UML is more commonly applied, is that you don't need a spork class to define things which are both spoons and forks - whether things belong to a classifier is defined by whether they meet the requirements of the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

*It's is a `Dependency`.
Dependency is a weaker form of relationship which indicates that one class depends on another because it uses it at some point of time. One class depends on another if the latter is a parameter variable or local variable of a method of the former. This is different from an association, where an attribute of the former is an instance of the latter.*

In other words your `somethingStance` class will use both `Cat` and `Panzer`

The below it is just an example of how it might look like

```
Public class SomethingStrange{
     public Cat CatDependency{get;set;}
     public Panzer PanzerDependency{get;set;}   

}
```

Comment: Well, realization is a form of dependency, but i still cant understand why InstanceSpecification has ability to represent more then one classifier. 

Spec says: 
"If multiple classifiers are specified, the instance is classified
by all of them."

In code generatioin what would happen?

Comment: it is not a Generalization and we are not talking about Multiple-Inheritance here. SomeThingClass will probably uses Cat or Panzer or both of them at some point

SomethingStangerClass IS NOT a subtype of Cat or Panzer

Comment: I think we need to find out first if the diagram is right, it doesn't exactly match the question...

Comment: but there is no SomethingStangerClass, "somethingStrange" is an InstanceSpecification, associated with two classes

Comment: yeah, this diagram could be wrong, sorry, my question was actually about "7.3.22 InstanceSpecification (from Kernel)" part of the specification, there it says that an instance specification is described by "Classification of the entity by one or more classifiers of which the entity is an instance." So i wonder how an entity could be an instance of more than one classifier.

Comment: following your definition we are talking about Multiple-Inheritance which means that a class can "extend" two different base class at the same time. Most of of OOP language does not allow you to do that but you can work around this limitation using interfaces

Comment: So UML tool must create that missing class for me?
Because if such a class has already exists, why not just put it in "classifiers my instance realize" and restrict that set to "at most 1"?

Answer (score 0):

That's multiple inheritance if you're referring to classes (except that you should use solid edges for generalization), [nothing wrong with that](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MultipleInheritanceIsNotEvil) ;)

Note that an interface is also a classifier, so also the text of your question needs a bit of refinement -- nothing wrong with generalizing more than one interface, after all.

Comment: as you said it should have solid edges otherwise is a "Relationship"

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso between classifiers, an open triangle with a dashed line is an interface realisation.

Answer (score 0):

UML does allow an object to be instance of several different classes (even if they are unrelated) at the same time. The fact that this is not the normal convention and not supported by programming languages is a different issue. UML tries to be as broad as possible even if specific technologies only can implement a subset of it.